# Bash: Check current day time against "allow string"

Tags: bash, awk, grep

This might be a bit strange.  I have a string that indicates all of the "allowed" times per week.  The String is 168 characters long.  Each of the characters is either a 1 or a 0.  Each character represents one hour of the week.  So, the first 24 characters in the string indicate the "allowed" hours for Sunday.  The next 24 characters are Monday and so on.  The number 1 represents "allowed" and the number 0 represents not allowed.  Here is a sample string:

```
 000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000
```

This string indicates allowed times between 6AM and 9PM Sunday through Saturday.  Many times there will be different allowed hours for different days of the week.  I'm trying to figure out it bash if the current day time is "allowed".

I've figured out that these tell me the current day and time:

```
 DATE=$(date)
 day=$(echo $DATE | cut -d' ' -f1)
 time=$(echo $DATE | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d: -f1-2 | tr -d ':')
```

However, I can't figure out an elegant way of comparing those to my long string.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Please note:**  I am using BusyBox 1.19.4.  That means that awk, sed, grep, etc may not be full-featured. :-(

EV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another bash version which may help you. I am assuming that the input string is stored in a file and will be passed as an argument to the script :

```
i=`expr $(date +%w) \\* 24 + $(date +%H) + 1`

i=$(cat $1 | awk -v I=${i} '{print substr($0,I,1)}')

if [ $i -eq 1 ]
then echo "BUSY"
elif [ $i -eq 0 ]
then echo "FREE"
else
echo "error : input string is shorter than expected" 
fi
```

If you want to pass the string as a parameter instead of a file, just replace the *'cat $1'* part of the 2nd statement to :

```
echo $1
```

NB : In case input string is shorter than the i value, you will two error messages from shell "*[: -eq: unary operator expected*" for the two *if* conditions along with the 3rd *echo* statement. So you may want to improve the *if* conditions a bit.

Again, the above piece of code is valid only when the start of the week is Sunday 0th hour. Otherwise some other mapping must be used.

Comment: I'm stuck on busybox 1.19.4 and I'm getting a "substitution error" on this line: i=${seq:i:1}.  I'm sure this script works on a more complete shell...unfortunately, it doesn't work on mine. :-(

Comment: ${seq:i:1} is a bash syntax. I'm not familiar to busybox. However it can be replaced by other ways I guess.

Comment: Now have a look at the edit. I replaced the annoying part with AWK. And also corrected the 1st statement(instead of multiplying week no with 24, I was squaring it).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Here is awk solution to do it in one shot. (without `date` stuff):

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="24 24 24 24 24 24 24" '{split(strftime("%w,%H", systime()),t,",");for(i=0;i<7;i++)a[i]=$(i+1);print substr(a[t[1]],t[2]+1,1)?"OK":"NOK"}' file
```

for better reading:

```
  awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="24 24 24 24 24 24 24" '{
        split(strftime("%w,%H", systime()),t,",")
        for(i=0;i<7;i++) a[i]=$(i+1)
        print substr(a[t[1]],t[2]+1,1)?"OK":"NOK"
   }' file
```

if I run this now, `(here is Wed. 10:58 AM)`, it outputs:

```
OK
```

please test it with your real data, and report if it works. :)

Comment: I like the looks of this but it did not work for me.  No matter what my file contains (all 1's for example) it returns NOK. :-(

Comment: @exvance is your awk gnu awk?

Comment: It is the awk included in busybox 1.19.4...which I'm sure has all the cool features removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash only version

```
startoweek=`date +%s -d 20130717`
#1373999400

current=$(date +%s)
let diff=(${current}-${startoweek})/3600

if [ $diff -ge 168 ]
then echo "Old Timetable"
exit
fi

work=000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000000000111111111111111000
allowed=${work:$diff:1}
if [ $allowed -eq 1 ]
then echo "Welcome"
elif [ $allowed -eq 0 ]
then echo "Go Home"
else
echo "Error"
fi
```